# What is the meaning of "^" in prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I have a knowledge base about movies. My actor and actress predicates look like this:

```
% actor(M,A,R) -- actor A played role R in movie M
% actress(M,A,R) -- actress A played role R in movie M
```

I'm trying to count the distinct actors and actresses in my knowledge base.
I would simply write:

```
count(Nr):-
setof(Name,actor(Movie,Name,Role),List1),
setof(Name,actress(Movie,Name,Role),List2),
length(List1,Nr1),
length(List2,Nr2),
Nr is Nr1+Nr2.
```

It doesn't work, but that way it does:

```
count(Nr):-
setof(Name,(Movie^Role^actor(Movie,Name,Role)),List1),
setof(Name,(Movie^Role^actress(Movie,Name,Role)),List2),
length(List1,Nr1),
length(List2,Nr2),
Nr is Nr1+Nr2.
```

So what does that "^"?

Edit: It looks like is something about selecting just once every movie and every role. But I'm still not sure.

Comment: It's used in `setof` as an *existential quantifier*. Here's a tutorial which describes it a little: [Prolog: finding all answers](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_12.html)